# JPA SQL select and sum from entity manager

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, entity

The following SQL script works in mysql:

```
select 
    LOGGING_ID,
    SUM(NORMAL_HOURS +OVERTIME_HOURS +DOUBLE_TIME_HOURS) AS TOTAL_HOURS
FROM
    LOGGING_DETAIL
GROUP BY 1
```

How would I do this with my entity manager?:

```
@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager database;

    List<loggingDetail> loggingDetail = new ArrayList<loggingDetail>();
    timeLoggingDetail = database.createQuery("").getResultList();
```

at the end I want the Logging_id and the total hours for that ID.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity manager could called a named query that you set on your jpa entity object. I am assuming you have an entity object in this case. I suppose if you don't have that object you could do it in the query like you have it laid out in your question.  I like having it in the entity object though so other calls can re-use it.

Entity object -

```
 @Entity
 @NamedQuery( name = "loggingDetail.getLoggingId", query = "select 
LOGGING_ID,SUM(NORMAL_HOURS +OVERTIME_HOURS +DOUBLE_TIME_HOURS) AS TOTAL_HOURS
 FROM LOGGING_DETAIL GROUP BY 1" )
public class LoggingDetail
{ ...}
```

The entity manager call will not get a fully populated loggingDetail object back since the query is not returning a full object, so you have to loop through an object array  -

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager database;
Query query = database.createNamedQuery( "loggingDetail.getLoggingId" );
List<Object[]> obj = query.getResultList();
    for( Object[] objects : obj )
    {
      String logId = (String) objects[0] ;
      String logTime = (String) objects[1] ;
     }
```